# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Connection::prepare

Tags: php

My connection class:

```
class Connection{

private $host="localhost";
private $user="root";
private $password="";
private $dbname="test";         

private function conectionDB(){
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname","$this->user", "$this->password");
    return $conn;           
}

public function __contruct(){
    return $this->conectionDB();           
}
}
```

My index.php:

```
 <?php   
require_once('class/Connection.class.php');
$pdo_conn = new Connection();
$query = "select * from qualquercoisa"
$pdo_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare($query);

 ?>
```

**Error:**
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Connection::prepare()

Comment: This is not duplicated

Comment: two things:  1) you're using a construct method that is deprecated in php7; use __construct instead of the class name.  2)  You forgot to put a `return $this` in the construct method.  I think you've got a good start; I'd go ahead and make `Connection` into an abstraction, which would allow you to create find, update, insert, and delete methods which would simplify your code considerably.  FWIW, this post does not look like a newbie to me; it very well could be a ruby programmer trying to use php. This mistake has bitten me a couple of times...

Comment: I modified, but I still have a problem.

Comment: you made 2 typos and php's error reporting would have helped you here.

Comment: to which and to mark the question as properly duplicated, another was added.